# Uploading a simple web2py app to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I created a web2py app that is extremely light, with the goal of eventually making the app support JSON-RPC calls, and maybe a few other things.

I found some tutorial online that (on winxp) had me get the source code for web2py and extract it on top of the compiled program.  At the top level, I edited app.yaml with my program name and used the GAE SDK to upload the program.  It looks like that uploaded everything including example applications.  I think it's including a whole gluon directory, and other dir's full of py files.  Is there a way to setup web2py to only upload my application, and what's minimally required to run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app.yaml that comes with web2py includes a section skip_files and it should contain, among others, this line:

(applications/(admin|examples)/.*)|

You can change it to

(applications/(admin|examples|welcome)/.*)|

So that welcome app is not deployed. You add more apps that you may have and do not want deployed.

At minimum you need:

- web2py/gaehandler.py
- web2py/gluon/* (and subfolders, this is web2py)
- web2py/applications/theoneappyouwanttodeploy/* (and subfolders)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I also found I needed web2py/VERSION to get the page to work.  One last thing, I did some experimentation and also found that without wsgihandler.py the page took several seconds to load.  Is there a way to change a script so web2py doesn't hangup if wsgihandler.py is missing?

Comment: odd. web2py on GAE does not use wsgihandler.py

Comment: I did as explained above, but welcome app still seems to be deployed. When browsed from Google App Launcher it still shows Welcome app. From there I can even log in and run Admin app. URL is like the following: http://localhost:8080/admin/default/site. Why is it that?

Comment: Okay, I've noticed that when deployed locally in App Engine SDK, all web2py apps are accessible; however, when deployed to google production server app.yaml settings take effect.